# How do I designate part of a code listing transparent and another part not?

Tags: listings, transparency

Let's say I have a code segment as follows:

```
function foo() {
   ... // Lots of code not shown here
}
```

Then, let's assume I add some changes that I'd like to highlight over the old code.

```
function foo() {
   ...
   // New code here
   ...
}
```

What I'd like is to be able to make some parts of the code ``transparent'' and others not, similar to how GitHub shows changes between commits (without the green and red colors).

Here's a small example of what I'm after: we have a code listing where everything in between the (* and *) are delimiters denoting ``old code'', or code that should be transparent in the listing.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
(*
function foo() {
  ...
*)
  // New code here
(*
  ...
}
*)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here's an actual example with code. I want to designate part of a region as transparent, but even with the `escapeinside` field set, it won't work.

```
\lstset{
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    language=C
}

\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
    (*@\transparent{0.55}@*)
    return 0;
    (*@\transparent{1.0}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this suffice? You can refer to the documentation of listings package for more fine-tuning.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    moredelim=[s][\transparent{0.5}]{(*}{*)},
}

\begin{lstlisting}
    int main() {
        (*
        // old code
        return 1;
        *)
        // new code
        return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the idea was that the delimiters (* *) would be omitted from the listing, meaning the only thing that's present is "// old code return 1;"